# About print page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I already tried with this code

```
$('textarea').each(function() {

   this.style.height = 'auto';

   this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';

});
```

Then I'm able to get the full content with specified height in edit page like this jpg format [Edit page View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIzaP.png)

But I'm not getting the same in print page this is my issue
[Print page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loRJc.png).

Can anyone please help me about this issue?

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit further??

Comment: Actually i'm not able to get an full content of the textarea in print page